# MSBuild not placing files where requested

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

So coming across a very strange issue with MSbuild using TFS 2015 build definition.

The web application I am trying to build has multiple csprojs that are used as class libraries throughout the application and of course my actual web application.

Bellow are the MSBuild arguments I am passing through currently to get a fully completed build.

```
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True
/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False /p:OutDir=C:\Agent\_work\1\s\Application\Package\bin\
/p:WebProjectOutputDir=C:\Agent\_work\1\s\Application\Package\WebSite\
/p:NoWarn=0067 
/v:Minimal
```

What I would actually like to do is the following.

```
    /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=True
/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=False /p:OutDir=C:\Agent\_work\1\s\Application\Package\Website\bin\
/p:WebProjectOutputDir=C:\Agent\_work\1\s\Application\Package\WebSite\
/p:NoWarn=0067 
/v:Minimal
```

The issue I run in to is after the first assemblies are run and placed in the bin folder it then works on the main webproject csproj and throws a unable to locate file for copy message.

I don't understand why this would be the case? Is it because MSBuild is expecting the bin folder to be empty/not there?

Am I missing something in the build order or different Argument needs to be passed. I have also to tried 'outpath' as well.

Comment: if would help you figure the issue out if you wernt turning off most of the logging, remove minimal,

Comment: Ok thanks James I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second arguments, the "OutDir" path is the same with "WebProjectOutputDir". This cause the issue since MSBuild will clean the "WebProjectOutputDir" folder before run "_WPPCopyWebApplication" task which copies files to "WebProjectOutputDir" folder. That means the files generated in "OutDir" during the build will be cleaned because it use the same path with "WebProjectOutputDir", so the task will cannot locate the files to copy.

To avoid this issue, you'd either change the "OutDir" different with "WebProjectOutputDir" or add one more arguments:

```
/p:CleanWebProjectOutputDir=False
```